# ESCPOS Datamatrix command

Tags: printing, escpos

I am trying to print a Datamatrix barcode using an EPSON m30 Printer.

When the following HEX values are transmitted, no action is taken.

I was able to get this HEX value from the page below.
https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=170

1d 28 6b 0d  00 36 50 30 31 32 33 34  35 36 37 38 39 30
1d 28  6b 03 00 36 54 30 0d 0a

Can you please let me know if something is wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the description on the reference page is incorrect.

For example, the printing of the Aztec code is [Function 581](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=165), which is 35 51 30.
The second byte of other barcodes is 51.

By analogy, there is a possibility of 36 51 30 instead of 36 54 30.
Please try sending the following command.

Q:

```
1d 28 6b 0d 00 36 50 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 1d 28 6b 03 00 36 54 30 0d 0a
```

A:

```
1d 28 6b 0d 00 36 50 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 1d 28 6b 03 00 36 51 30 0d 0a
```

Comment: You are an outstanding expert in the field of Printer Emulation. Thank you very much. Your answer solved the problem.